# How to suppress items with NULL value from HighCharts legend

Tags: highcharts

I've created a HighCharts donut graph. It will be filled with live data through a backend process. However, some of the data will have a 'name' but a NULL value for 'y'. I want to suppress these items in the legend.
See the example fiddle here:

```
  events: {
      load: function() {
        this.series.forEach(function(s) {
          s.data.forEach(function(d) {
            if (d.y === null) {
              d.setVisible(false)
              }
            });
          })
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2sw6b4e/

Here, the "Chrome" item has a NULL value.

I've managed to grey out the item in question but how to remove it altogether from the legend??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the below small plugin to filter out points with null `y` value.

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Legend.prototype, 'getAllItems', function(proceed) {
        var allItems = proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        return allItems.filter(function(item) {
            return item.y !== null;
        });
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uLn4ya6r/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: That looks good, thanks!
However, I need all code to be within the 

Highcharts.chart('container', {

because of the way it is processed in the code. If I put your function in the chart.events.load then it does not work. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Hi @Hans Wijnveen, Please check a workaround for your case in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/owzm0823/